# Function to return a formatted string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

A function which returns a formatted string by replacing all instances of `%X` with `Xth` argument in `args (0...len(args))`

Example:

```
simple_format("%1 calls %0 and %2", "ashok", "hari")=="hari calls ashok and %2"
```

Please help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> "{1} calls {0} and {2}".format( "ashok", "hari", "tom")
'hari calls ashok and tom'
```

If you really need the function `simple_format`, then:

```
import re
def simple_format(*args):
    s = re.sub(r'%(\d+)', r'{\1}', args[0])
    return s.format(*args[1:])
```

Example:

```
>>> simple_format("%1 calls %0 and %2", "ashok", "hari", "tom")
'hari calls ashok and tom'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example utilising `string.Template`:

```
from string import Template

def simple_format(text, *args):
    class T(Template):
        delimiter = '%'
        idpattern = '\d+'
    return T(text).safe_substitute({str(i):v for i, v in enumerate(args)})

simple_format("%1 calls %0 and %2", "ashok", "hari")
# hari calls ashok and %2
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

```
"{1} calls {0} and {2}".format("hari", "ashok", "x")
>>> 'ashok calls hari and x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Function to return a formatted string in python:

```
def simple_format(format, *args):
"""
Returns a formatted string by replacing all instances of %X with Xth argument in args (0...len(args))
e.g. "%0 says hello", "ted" should return "ted says hello"
"%1 says hello to %0", ("ted", "jack") should return jack says hello to ted etc.
If %X is used and X > len(args) it is returned as is.
"""
pass
count = 0
for name in args:
    format = format.replace("%" + str(count), name)
    count = count + 1
return format
```