# Return a formatted string #3

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, format, return

I need a self contained function that does / returns the formatted string, rather than formatting the string after it is returned.
None of the other questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807128/return-formatted-string-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260017/function-to-return-a-formatted-string-in-python), were asking what I wanted for the keywords I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question

```
def right_just_string(string):
    # return a string that is padded by say 10 chars
    return str(f'{string:>10}')

thing = 'cat'
print(thing)
print(right_just_string(thing))

returns
cat
       cat
```

Yes it's simple but I was asking the question when my string and formatting was complex - I didn't even know it was possible